# PHP file not working in subdirectory protected by .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-7

I have a directory, lets call it `sub`, which is a sub-directory of the root directory.

In this subdirectory I have a `.htaccess` file which looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Initial Zugriff verweigert - Bitte Authentifizieren Sie sich."
AuthUserFile sub/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

DirectoryIndex info.php
```

`sub/` also contains the files: `info.php` and the `.htpasswd` file.

Whereas `info.php` is a simple php file like this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

When I put `info.php` into the root directory or delete the `.htaccess` file it works just fine and shows me the php7 informations, but when put behind the `.htaccess` file it gives me a

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm not able to access the apache error logs since I'm on a shared hosting server from 1und1.

I'm thinking the `.htaccess` is the problem and I have to allow php to work in the protected directory. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: i think your path to htpasswd file should be AuthUserFile .htpasswd  instead of AuthUserFile /sub/.htpasswd in htaccess file

Comment: you can remove or rename the .htaccess. Especially if there is no .htpasswd.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log for the reason of 500 error. It could be due to permissions on `.htpasswd` file. It should be kept outside `DocumentRoot` for security reasons.

Comment: @anubhava as i said i don't have access to the apache error logs.

Comment: @Calimero well there is a .htpasswd in the same directory as the .htaccess file.

Comment: @anubhava and neither of them are in the documentroot, they are in the sub directory.

Comment: @anubhava so you have no idea aswell?

Comment: `AuthUserFile` needs full filesystem path not website path. `AuthUserFile /sub/.htpasswd` means `/sub/` must be a valid filesystem path and there should be a directory `sub` directly filesystem root. Does `ls -al /sub/` show you password file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: @aynber i already enabled this but it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: @anubhava will check this later, thanks for the help.

Comment: @anubhava the Comment `ls -al sub` gave me the password file.

Comment: @anubhava Well you were right on that one, i changed the line in the .htaccess file to `AuthUserFile sub/.htpasswd` so that `ls -al sub/` gave me my .htpasswd .

Comment: This doesn't change the outcome tho, i still get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @anubhava when using the full system path the authentication on the web doesn't work anymore... like in he doesnt seem to find the `.htpasswd` file anymore when using the full filesystempath.
What does it even matter, the authentication does work when using it like this: `AuthUserFile sub/.htpasswd`.
what else could cause a 500er Error?